# I cannot access the login page

Tags: 6, users

I have to change a website, but I cannot log in. The problem is, that the login page does not appears in any way. I get a 403 error when accessing /user. That should come from a change that I did in the past to deactivate the [login page at all](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19324/disable-login-at-all). Even I cannot remember what I did or (last conclusion), the database has an error and the login page does not appear.

I setup a new Drupal installation with the same version, but I cannot see any significant difference of the folders.

Is there a *hack* to activate for a moment to allow anonymous user act as an administrator?

I am using Drupal 6.19.

Querying the database, I get the following.

```
    drupal=> SELECT path FROM menu_router WHERE path LIKE '%user%';
     user/login
     user/password
     user/register
     user/autocomplete
     admin/user
     user/%
     user/%/view
     user/login/lightbox2
     user/login/thickbox
     admin/user/rules
     admin/help/user
     user/%/contact
     user/%/delete
     admin/user/permissions
     admin/user/roles
     admin/user/settings
     admin/user/user
     user/%/edit
     admin/user/rules/list
     admin/user/user/list
     user/%/edit/account
     admin/user/rules/add
     admin/user/user/create
     admin/user/rules/check
     admin/user/roles/edit
     admin/user/rules/edit
     admin/user/rules/delete
     admin/views/ajax/autocomplete/user
     user/reset/%/%/%
    (30 rows)
```

Comment: If it's a database problem, you can try clearing the cache with `drush cc all` and hope that the problem resolvs itself.

Comment: I tried this already, no success.

Comment: Then I think we can rule out "database has an error". Does the user paths get registered? What is the output of `SELECT path FROM menu_router WHERE path LIKE "%user%";`? If any module denies access to the login form, try disabling any non-core modules with drush, clear the cache again, and see if that helps.

Comment: just shooting in the dark here.. but is there a difference in `page_callback`, `page_arguments`, `access_callback`, `access_arguments`and `include_file` between stock drupal (which uses core user module) installation and the troubled installation for entry user/login.. maybe using [`drush uli`](http://drush.ws/#user-login) to try login to site might help do some damage control..

Answer (score 1):

Try accessing user/logout, and then log in the usual way.

Answer (score 1):

There is hack to logged into site if you do not have admin details of the site. I I do not prefer this method but as you have disabled the login form, then it would be good solution for you.

There is `{sessions}` table in Drupal database which stored the sessions of the user into site. You can follow the below step:

- Empty the `{sessions}` table in your database.
- Visit the site as anonymous user
- Check `{sessions}` table in database and you will find the entry in table for the anonymous user. There is '0' value is saved in `uid` column of database table.
- Edit `uid` column and modify value from 0 to 1.

Kindly see that it's not standard solution to login into site.

Comment: Or use drush, `drush uli` gives you a temporarily link to log in even if login form is not working.

Answer (score 0):

You could :

- dump the DB + files on a local test server
- remove all non core modules
- reset the password of on of the user inside the user table

Don't do this on production if possible.

See http://drupal.org/node/44164

Answer (score 0):

Since you followed answers to this [Disable login at all](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/19324/disable-login-at-all#answer-19407) ,may be you already set this FALSE! You checked this?

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'user_login') {
    $form['#access'] = FALSE;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try and access the password reset page (/user/password), or, alternatively, use `drush uli` from the command line. Both will provide you with a reset link (the first by mail, so you should have functioning mail sending on the server), that will bypass the login page but get you a logged in session. Of course, whether this works completely depends on how thorough you were trying to prevent people from logging in.